# Building a hash table and perfect hash function in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, hash, perfect-hash

I'm working with the Google Maps API and feel there is a better way to search through the panorama images other then a massive `switch` statement. I would think that using an external hash table would be far more efficient and much easier to maintain. Each image has a unique `panoID`, which I would be able to define. Reading up on hash tables, I believe I am correct in saying I could make a table and perfect function to get the data I need in constant time. Is there a good resource on how to build this? I am not experienced with hashing at all.

My logic goes as this: Each image is saved in a directory as `sometext_panoID.jpg`, where `sometext` is a string and `panoID` is anything I want it to be. When initializing the data in the aforementioned switch statement, all the switching is done according to the panoID and the other metadata is accessed there. For example:

```
switch(panoID) {
    case "test1":
      links.push({
        description : "TEST2",
        pano : "test2",
        heading : 70
      });
      break;
    case "test2":
      links.push({
        description : "TEST1",
        pano : "test1",
        heading : 125
      });
      links.push({
        description : "TEST3",
        pano : "test3",
        heading : 0
      });
      break;
      case "test3":
      links.push({
        description : "TEST2",
        pano : "test2",
        heading : 0
      });
      break;
  }
```

Since I will know all the `panoID`s, and will have no need to sort, add, or otherwise change anything once the table is built, I feel there is a way to make a perfect hash but don't really know where to start. Any tips? Thank's a bunch in advance

Comment: Given an array of strings, it is possible to generate a [minimal perfect hash function](https://github.com/mixu/perfect) for those strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, simple plain objects with their properties are implemented as hash tables underneath. So there is no need to read about hashing algorithms, you can have that work done by your JS engine:

```
var table = {
    "test1": [
      {
        description : "TEST2",
        pano : "test2",
        heading : 70
      }
    ],
    "test2": [
      {
        description : "TEST1",
        pano : "test1",
        heading : 125
      },
      {
        description : "TEST3",
        pano : "test3",
        heading : 0
      }
    ],
    "test3": [
      {
        description : "TEST2",
        pano : "test2",
        heading : 0
      }
    ]
};

var itemstobepushed = table[panoID];
[].push.apply(links, itemstobepushed);
```

Comment: Well. That sure is convenient. I should've mentioned in the OP i'm new to JS as well, so could you expand on the last two lines a bit? If I understand correctly, `var itemstobepushed = table[panoID];` will get the data at that `panoid` and put it in `itemstobepushed`, and the next line will do what exactly?

Comment: It uses the [`apply` method of functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to call the [Array `push` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) with a variable number of arguments. A loop and `links.push(itemstobepushed[i])` might be more convenient…

Comment: Hm ok i'll have to look into this further.